# Canvas is always null

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have a recurring problem. Whenever I try to access the 2d context of my canvas element (already in my html) to draw an image I get a console error telling me I can't draw to null. (Cannot call method 'drawImage' of null) 
I'm on the third rewrite, started in JS now in jquery. Tried moving the scripts around in the html. I don't get it. Surely the canvas element already exists because the DOM is ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function setup(){

var canvas = document.getElementById("canv1");
console.log(canvas.toString());
//this grabs hold of the canvas api
var canvcontext = canvas.getContext('2D');
console.log(canvcontext.toString());


burpy = new Image();
burpy.onload = canvcontext.drawImage(burpy,400,100);
burpy.src = 'burpy.png';
};


setup();
});
```

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JAVASCRIPT TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="parse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<body id="body">
    Silly video games
    <br>    

<canvas id="canv1" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<div id="canvwrap">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `canvas.getContext('2d');` instead of `canvas.getContext('2D');`

Comment: +1 Beat me to it - it is case sensitive! Here is the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/WXUSg/

Comment: I am about to go and throw myself against a wall. Thank you very much for this answer. I think you were dead right. I am now getting the context in my variable.